# Enqueue CSS in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm at my wit's end here... here is the code I use to try and get a CSS file to work in my WordPress plugin:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'initial_admin_links_hide_stylesheet');

function initial_admin_links_hide_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('initial_hide_admin_links.css', __FILE__));   
}
```

Then I call the function by using this line of code:

```
initial_admin_links_hide_stylesheet();
```

If I comment out the call to the function I receive no notices. If I leave it uncommented, the notice I receive is:

**Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home2/jakereva/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3547**

As far as I can tell, the code has been written correctly, but I absolutely cannot get that notice to go away when I call the function. Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'initial_admin_links_hide_stylesheet');
```

This tells Wordpress to hook the script into the process for you. There is no need to call the function manually.

Make sure you have wp_head() and wp_footer() calls in your theme files where appropriate or it want be added

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: If I take out the function call (initial_admin_links_hide_stylesheet();), the CSS never displays. If I leave it in, the CSS executes, but I get the notice. In my own header.php file, I do have a wp_head() call.

Comment: Two things here. 1) You also have to have wp_footer() call in your footer. 2) Not that important but I try to always do the add_action after I declare the function.

Comment: I'm using the parent theme's footer.php file, so there's a call to the footer in there. Changing the position of the add_action doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Change hook name to wp_head. This will enqueue style in header.

Check the WordPress action reference to see what actions being called. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

In front you can use wp_head.
In admin pages: admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: The notice goes away, but the CSS never gets called/loaded

Comment: Check the WordPress action reference to see what actions being called. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference